# Activity Information Fields

Tags: event, activities, custom-reports

While creating a report on Events and Activities, I can see the following fields available. [image]

However, these fields are neither available on Event nor or Activity. I have checked the field list from setup and also from "open resource" on the developer console. I don't understand, Where are these fields fetched from.

I need to know, because I want to round off these fields and then use it in the report. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events and Tasks are oddball objects; they don't always work like everything else because they're very nearly "subclasses" of an abstract Activity object. This can be very confusing with regard to their field availabilities. I find that the SOAP reference, which I link below, is the easiest reference to the objects.

`DurationInMinutes` is a field on [Event only](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_event.htm). I believe "Duration (Hours)" is a special-case reporting convenience; it's not part of the schema. `DurationInMinutes` is required to match the difference between `StartDateTime` and `EndDateTime` if both it and `EndDateTime` are populated.

`CallDurationInSeconds` is a field on [Task only](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_task.htm#!).